# Why do I need an admin password to change the VPN PPP Password in my keychain?

Tags: vpn, keychain

It's MY local personal keychain after all. I can edit other passwords, but not the VPN PPP pasword. See screenshot for details.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because VPN is a network interface, your basically changing preferences for that (so that´s a global change, not only for your keychain item). So the same way you need to identify as an admin to unlock "System Preferences...">"Network" for being able to change interfaces, you would need to do that here, too.

Comment: Hmm. I wish the resources would be local, I don't want other users on the machine to have access to my VPN connection.

Comment: They DO NOT have access to your VPN configuration (unless they use sudo), and DO NOT have access to your VPN unless they are logged in at the same time, but the possibility of exactly this happening (a standard user re-routing network-connections that could affect other users on the same system) is what requires admin privileges.

Answer (score -1):

Because it's YOUR keychain. This prevents someone else from sitting down at your computer and changing your keychain passwords.

Comment: Wait... so why do you need _any_ administrator's username and password there?

Comment: Because you are the administrator of your computer.